# Derivative of sum of two functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to find $\frac{dy}{dx}\left[(x\sqrt{x})+\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x}}\right]$ but would like to find where I made a mistake in my solution.

Here is my work:
\begin{align} 
(f+g)'=& \ f'+g', f = x \sqrt{x}, g= \frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt x}\\ f=& \ x \cdot x^{1/2} = x^{3/2} 
\\ f'=& \  \frac{3}{2x\sqrt{x}} \\ \\ 
g =& \ x^{-2}\cdot x^{-1/2} \\ g =& \ x^{-5/2} \\ g' =& \ -\frac{5}{2x^3 \sqrt{x}} \\ \\ f'+g' =& \ \frac{3}{2x\sqrt{x}} - \frac{5}{2x^3 \sqrt{x}} \\ =& \ \frac{3x^2-5}{2x^3 \sqrt x} \\ \frac{dy}{dx}=& \ \frac{\sqrt x (3x^2-5)}{2x^4}
\end{align}

Comment: The first derivative is incorrect

Comment: So let's look at
$$
f = x^{3/2}
$$
Its derivative is of course
$$
f' = \frac{3}{2} x^{\frac{3}{2} - 1} = \frac{3}{2} x^{1/2}
$$
So just be careful with this, okay?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[(x\sqrt{x})+\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x}}\right]$$$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\sqrt{x}\right)+\frac{d}{dx}\ \left(\frac{1}{x^{2}\sqrt{x}}\right)$$$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)+\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{\large-\frac{5}{2}}\right)$$$$=\frac{3}{2}\large x^{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{5}{2}\large x^{-\frac{7}{2}}$$$$=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{x}-\frac{5}{2\sqrt{x^{7}}}$$

In most high school calculus books the power rule for derivatives is proven used binomial theorem, but binomial theorem is not helpful for all arbitrary real powers.

For more information about the derivation of the function $x^{n}$ for all real $n,x$ refer to the [link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Rule_for_Derivatives)

Answer (score 0):

In general if $f(x)=x^{n}$ for some constant $n$ then $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$ which is the power rule.